# Elastic Search: Matching sub token default operator

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there a way to set the default operator for sub tokens (tokens generated through the analyzer)? It currently seems to default to OR and setting `operator` does not work.

I'm using the validate API to see how Elastic Search is understanding the query:

```
/myIndex/mapping/_validate/query?explain=true

{
  "query":{
    "multi_match":{
      "type":"phrase_prefix",
      "query":"test123",
      "fields":[
        "message"
      ],
      "lenient":true,
      "analyzer":"myAnalyzer"
    }
  }
}
```

Which returns

```
+(message:test123 message:test message:123)
```

What I want is

```
+message:test123 +message:test +message:123
```

Is there any way to do this without using a script or splitting the terms and creating a more complex query in the application?

**EDIT**

Using `operator` or `minimum_should_match` does not make a difference.

My elastic search mapping for `myAnalyzer` is

```
{
  "analysis":{
    "filter":{
      "foldAscii":{
        "type":"asciifolding",
        "preserve_original":"1"
      },
      "capturePattern":{
        "type":"pattern_capture",
        "patterns":[
          "(\\p{Ll}+|\\p{Lu}\\p{Ll}+|\\p{Lu}+(?!\\p{Ll}+))",
          "(\\d+)"
        ]
      },
      "noDuplicates":{
        "type":"unique",
        "only_on_same_position":"true"
      }
    },
    "myAnalyzer":{
      "filter":[
        "capturePattern",
        "lowercase",
        "foldAscii",
        "noDuplicates"
      ],
      "tokenizer":"standard"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: could you add the return of the validate API when you add the "operator": "and" to the multi_match query ?

Comment: I'd like to avoid any extra network requests. Another thing I want to do is support phrase queries, but if I form all the terms myself then I have to also create my own span query (again, not ideal). I think my only remaining option is to change how the analyzer works as to not create so many sub tokens and then do a little application to magic to replace all separators with spaces so positional matching can work...

Comment: could you tell us what is the definition of myAnalyzer for a better comprehension of your problem ?

Comment: @PierreMallet I realized I didn't answer your original question. With that field added, it returns the same thing: `+(message:test123 message:test message:123)`. It doesn't seem like ES is respecting my options for `operator` or `minimum_should_match` (at least the documentation indicates it should do what I want). I'll update my original post the with the mapping definition

Comment: Just for info match phrase and match phrase prefix query dont seems to handle operator or minimum should match. You try to rewrite your query as a bool query

Comment: Another thing I learned is that the `pattern_capture` token filter creates all the tokens in the same position and offset. Surprisingly Elastic Search treats these as synonyms and provides no way of working around it.